# NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am using Hibernate c3p0's Connection Pool

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

the dependency is defined in my pom.xml, and jar inside the library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The C3P0 connector gets picked up while starting my application:

```
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Sep 10, 2014 7:39:39 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/myDatabase
Sep 10, 2014 7:39:39 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
```

However, the code breaks at line 21:

```
3 | import org.hibernate.Session;
4 | import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
5 | import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
6 | import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
...
...
19 | Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
20 | StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
21 | SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

And this is returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at com.boa.ecris.test.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I've been searching online for quite sometime for deprecated jars, etc. But no luck yet.
Any ideas?

Comment: Look this :) http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-errorinitial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-commchangev2c3p0datasources/

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources

The Error Itself says that it is not able to Find the **com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources** class from the jars which are added in your Maven Dependencies.
The Exception is thrown at the time when you are configuring the Hibernate i.e.,
at LINE 19:  Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

Please add the  **c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar** to the classpath or add the dependency in pom.xml from the link [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2).
In my case, it worked!! hope it helps you too...